# Umbraco 7.3.1 CurrentPage.Children issue

Tags: umbraco7

Consider this code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
@{ 
    var pages = @CurrentPage.Children; 
}

  <table style="width:100% !important">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Subbasin Name</td>
      <td style="width: 15% !important">Hydrologic Unit Code (HUC)</td>
      <td style="width: 25% !important">TMDL Status</td>
      <td style="width: 25% !important">Implementation Plan Status</td>
      <td style="width: 15% !important">Five Year Review Status</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var page in @pages){
      <tr>
        <td><a href="@page.URL">@page.pageTitle</a> <br />@page.watershedName</td>
        <td>@page.hydrologicUnitCode</td>
        <td>@page.tmdlStatus</td>
        <td>@page.implementationPlanStatus</td>
        <td>@page.fiveYearReviewStatus</td>
       </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Problem: The table draws and populates as desired but for one thing...

```
<a href="@page.URL">@page.pageTitle</a>
```

The URL of each of the child pages isn't right.. each row of the table has the right Title, and the other columns are correct, but the anchor is being formed with the URL of the CurrentPage rather than each Child's .Url. I assume I am doing something wrong, but I cannot see why this isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem - case sensitivity (duh).
Changing:

```
<a href="@page.URL">@page.pageTitle</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="@page.Url">@page.pageTitle</a>
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Surely you mean page.URL to page.Url?

Comment: Thank you Jannik! I neglected to use code tags in my post, so it read entirely wrong as you pointed out. Edited.